# Optimization in Matlab : Is it possible to access the mesh size information inside the objective function?

Tags: matlab, optimization, parameters

I'm performing an optimization using patternsearch in Matlab, and I would like to modify a parameter of my objective function when the mesh size gets smaller. Is it possible to access the mesh size inside the objective function to implement a "if"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so due to the structure of the code. If you had the source code yes, but the way it works, you input a function for objective that has fixed input variables. Even if the information is inside `patternsearch`, the algorithm won't input it to your objective function thus you have no read access to it